# Show that linear predictor of a stationary Gaussian time series depends only on the first 2 moments of the series

Tags: time-series, predictive-models

I would like to convince myself that the best predictor of a stationary Gaussian time series depends on more than just the first 2 unconditional moments of the series, whereas the best linear predictor depends only on the first 2 moments. Let "best" be defined, as usual, in terms of minimal mean squared error.

"*... the fact that the best linear predictor depends only on the mean and the ACF of the series means that it can be calculated without more detailed knowledge of the joint distribution*" Brockwell & Davis page 40.

Comment: Moments of what exactly? Unconditional or conditional, and if so on what?

Comment: I edited my question to address your comment.

Comment: An infeasible optimal (under square loss) forecast of $x_{t+1}$ that follows a stationary AR(1) process $x_t=\varphi x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$ is $\varphi x_t$. If we can estimate $\varphi$ with sufficient precision (which we often can), this forecast will be better than the unconditional mean.

Comment: @RichardHardy: Thank your for that point, Richard. I feel, however, that you've misunderstood the question. I am not saying the best linear predictor is the unconditional mean but rather that it depends only on the first 2 moments. See Brockwell & Davis page 40, Mostly Harmless Econometrics (chapter 3) or Goldberger (chapter 5). I just haven't made peace yet with this result.

Comment: Right. I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x_t$ follows a stationary AR(1) process,
$$
x_t=\varphi x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t.
$$
An infeasible optimal* forecast of $x_{t+1}$ is $\hat{x}_{t+1|t}=\varphi x_t$. If we can estimate $\varphi$ with sufficient precision (which we often can, given a sufficiently large sample), this forecast will be better than a forecast that only depends on $\bar{x}$ and $\hat\sigma$, since $\varphi x_t$ cannot be expressed by them using a formula that is independent of $t$.

*Optimal under square loss = the one that minimizes the expected square error.

**Update:** this answer applies to my interpretation of the original post before clarification.

Comment: I edited my question by adding a quote from the textbook. Your answer would suggest the conclusion reached by Brockwell & Davis is incorrect, which I find to be unlikely.

Comment: @ColorStatistics, I did not consider ACF as part of "the first two moments". I would have to think about what happens when we include ACF in the information set. After some thought, I do not think you can recover $x_t$ from just the mean and the ACF, so you cannot obtain the infeasible optimal forecast $\varphi x_t$ nor, I guess, its feasible counterpart $\hat{\varphi} x_t$.

Comment: I see, yeah; apologies if I wasn't clear. This is a key result that suggests that working with covariance stationarity instead of strict stationarity is good enough if what we're after is the "best linear predictor". It is worth understanding this point thoroughly. I appreciate your time.

Comment: @ColorStatistics, here is a heuristic argument. You can turn the series around w.r.t. time without changing its mean or ACF. The optimal prediction for this version of the series should not be the same as for the original series, as $x_t$ and $x_1$ need not be equal. Thus I do not think the quote is right *without additional assumptions* or *without further qualifications*.